# WebLogic Server Forced Shut Down Automatically

Tags: weblogic, oracle-apex

I have developed an application in Oracle Apex 4.0 on Oracle 11g R2 on Solaris sparc 8 machine. My requirement was to run it via WebLogic Server. I configured Apex listener with WebLogic Server version 10.3.3.0 on Linux Red Hat 5.2 with Java Ver: 1.6.0-23. Everything is configured and works fine but as soon as I log out of the WebLogic server or the moment my session window to WebLogic server closes, WebLogic Server shutdown automatically. There is nothing in logs besides "SERVER_FORCED_SHUTDOWN" kind of message.

Please tell me where to check the server. Sometimes it works longer and then automatically shuts down and i have to restart it using command ./StartWebLogic.sh

Bundles of thanks in advance

Comment: If you are starting WebLogic by simply calling "./StartWebLogic.sh", it will indeed shut down once you close the session window. You need to start WebLogic server in background (by calling something like "nohup ./startWebLogic.sh &").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since my comment seems to have a nice acceptance (3 upvotes in 4 hours), and since you do not seem to have reputation enough to reply to my comment, I am adding it as a response:

If you are starting WebLogic by simply calling `./startWebLogic.sh`, it will indeed shut down once you close the session window. You need to start WebLogic server in background (by calling something like `nohup ./startWebLogic.sh &`).

Comment: hi.  Just checked it now. i am going to the production environment now and will run the command. thanks alot.